# Center text to parent element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center the text to a parent element. Here is my code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="header"><!--header-->
<span class="child">

<h1 class="h1temp">
        <div class="left">Hello</div>
        <div class="left down">There</div>
        <div class="left downer">James</div>
</h1>

</span>
</div><!--header-->
```

**CSS**

```
.header {
    height: 200px;
    background-color:#C0C0C0;
    position:relative;
}
.child {
    position:absolute;
    margin:50% auto;
    width:900px;
}
.h1temp {
    margin:0 auto;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

The problem is that the text aligns with the browser, not the parent element. Here is what it currently looks like [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rampill/5xBAw/2/).

Comment: It's not centered to the browser or the parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want to align `h1temp`.

`margin: x auto` only works if element has width`

```
.h1temp {
    margin:0 auto;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: I did not know that it had to have a set width. Thank you!

Comment: @Rampill If this answer resolved your issue, I would recommend marking it as the answer by clicking on the checkmark to the left of this post. This is so others with the same problem that find this post later on can know what the solution is and also benefit from your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just write `display:table;` to .h1temp